# is std::format at runtime possible?

Tags: c++, c++20, stdformat

Can I use a format string defined at runtime in a std::format?

[This seems to say](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/std::format-:-error-C7595/1694324) that you can't; that all format strings are a compile-time-only thing. I could have sworn that I did this only a few months ago, maybe it was before the Standard was regressed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <format>

std::string centre(std::string& string, const int width, const char fillchar = ' '){
    if (width <= string.size())
        return string;
    
    string = std::format("|{0:{1}^{2}}|", string, fillchar, width); //line 25
    return string;
}

int main() {
   std::cout << centre(s, 10, '*');
}
```

On building, I get the error

> string.cpp(25,24): error C7595: 'std::_Basic_format_string<char,row::string::str &,const size_t &,const char &>::_Basic_format_string': call to immediate function is not a constant expression

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Can I use a format string defined at runtime in a `std::format`?

[P2216](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2216r3.html#checks) makes `std::format` only accept compile-time string literals. For dynamic format strings, you can use [`std::vformat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/vformat).

It's worth noting that `std::format` still doesn't support parameterized fill characters due to performance issues (see [#2189](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/2189)), you may need to construct the format string for the format manually.

```
std::string centre(std::string string, int width, char fillchar = ' ') {
  if (width <= string.size())
    return string;
  std::string fmt_str = std::format("|{{:{}^{}}}|", fillchar, width);
  return std::vformat(fmt_str, std::make_format_args(string));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4hnYvMb6T)

Comment: Ta a lot for that. cppreference doesn't make it clear what vformat does in this regard.

Comment: So, to double-check, did `fmt::runtime_format` survive and could be used as `std::runtime_format`, or that part of P2216 was not taken in?

Comment: std::vformat suppose to support both std::string and std::wstring, but std::wstring just doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Right now you can do it with [`std::vformat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/vformat) (see 康桓瑋's answer) but in C++26 you'll be able to wrap your format string in [`std::runtime_format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/runtime_format):

```cpp
std::string centre(std::string_view string, int width, char fillchar = ' ') {
  std::string fmt = std::format("|{{:{}^{}}}|", fillchar, width);
  return std::format(std::runtime_format(fmt), string);
}
```

Comment: What is `std::runtime_string`?

Comment: It's a function: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/runtime_format

Comment: But in your code it's named differently.